# Dynamically creating elements based on json in REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am new on this forum and new in React Native. Could someone write me a piece of code to create form elements (image, toggle switch) based on json.

My JSON look like

> [{ "consumer": "S1", "status": "False"},{ "consumer": "S2", "status":
>   "False"},{"consumer": "S3", "status": "True"},{ "consumer": "S4",
>   "status": "False"},{ "consumer": "S7", "status": "False"}]

I would like to get i for each mode something like:

```
<View style={{width: '30%', height: 200}}>
          <Image
            source={
              require('../assets/images/s1.png') //sx
            }
            style={styles.welcomeImage}
          />

        </View>
        <View style={{width: '30%', height: 200}}>
          <Switch
            //here get status of s1..s8
        </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map through the array. Something like this:

```
render() {
  var consumers = [{ "consumer": "S1", "status": "False"},{ "consumer": "S2", "status": "False"},{"consumer": "S3", "status": "True"},{ "consumer": "S4", "status": "False"},{ "consumer": "S7", "status": "False"}];
  return (
    {consumers.map((c, i) => {
      return [
        <View style={{width: '30%', height: 200}}>
          <Image
            source={require('../assets/images/' + c.consumer + '.png')}
            style={styles.welcomeImage}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{width: '30%', height: 200}}>
          <Switch value={c.status} />
        </View>
      ]
    })}
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian but what is the easiest way to read this JSON to consumers variable and on what position, my JSON is actualy on [link](http://doen-international.eu/getTrosila.json)

Comment: Do you want to read the JSON in from an API call? If you're getting it from elsewhere I'd recommend getting the JSON in componentDidMount() and using setState to store it in your component state and then mapping that instead of a variable in the render function.

Comment: Or pass the JSON down as a prop from the parent component.

Comment: Wow Brian, you are so fast! Can you pass me a chunk of code beacuse I am still floating insecure in this waters :D

Comment: Thanks, Endi. I can, but I'm still not sure how you're getting the JSON. Is it hard-coded, are you getting it from an external source, is it being passed down from a parent?

Comment: Well, on the server (actually router) side I am fetching home status from arduino with PHP and I will construct new JSON on every call to that script. Right now I only would like to try parsing JSON from the link above.

On app start I would like to build interface according to that JSON and after to refresh every 10 seconds (only status, not everything)

If easier, it is ok to create all elements in code and only refresh status form JSON

Comment: I like [SuperAgent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/), so you could do something like this in your componentDidMount():

`
request.get('http://doen-international.eu/getTrosila.json').end((err, res) => {
  if (err) {
   console.error(err);
  } else if (response) {
    this.setState({consumers: response.body});
  }
}
`

Then map `this.state.consumers` in your render()